# always failed to ping ipv6 from AP to Sta

Tags: ping, ipv6

I have a AP and Sta connected wirelessly, configured as following:

- AP: `2001:db8:290c:1291::49/48`
- Station: `2001:db8:290c:1291::48/48`

when I do ping from AP to Station, it always show

```
PING 2001:db8:290c:1291::48 (2001:db8:290c:1291::48): 56 data bytes
```

it would only start to ping when I initiate ping from the Station to AP.
it show as following:

```
PING 2001:db8:290c:1291::48 (2001:db8:290c:1291::48):
56 data bytes from 2001:db8:290c:1291::48: seq=57 ttl=64 time=1933.558 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:290c:1291::48: seq=58 ttl=64 time=933.400 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:290c:1291::48: seq=59 ttl=64 time=2.025 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:290c:1291::48: seq=60 ttl=64 time=2.018 ms
```

It had been trouble me for a couple of days..
Anyone has any idea about this?
Appreciate that someone can give me a hint here..

Comment: Does the station at least reply to Neighbour Discovery packets? Since they are multicast, make sure that's allowed by the AP (unless it does ND proxying itself). Does the station have a "power save" mode? Try disabling it.

Comment: power save mode is disabled. I checked "ip neigh show" in both ap and sta.. it shows :                                                                        root@Client:~# ip neigh show
192.168.0.10 dev br-lan lladdr b0:83:fe:6c:29:96 DELAY
192.168.0.2 dev br-lan  FAILED
root@MASTER:~# ip neigh show
2001:db8:290c:1291::48 dev br-lan  FAILED
192.168.0.2 dev br-lan  FAILED

Comment: i still looking for answer for this case. Can I repost this question to ask around here